# Arduino does not recieve value from raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I have been trying to transfer co-ordinates from picamera of raspberry pi to arduino .It was running smoothly in python 2.7.But in python 3+ i had to encode the value using encode() function to before serial write .
But now the arduino does not receive any value at all.
Serial.read in arduino shows -1 value in serial monitor.
Can someone tell me what to do?

I have tried checking my connections.

```
        import io
        from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
        from picamera import PiCamera
        import time
        import sys
    sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages")
    import cv2
    import serial
    import numpy as np

    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 32
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
    port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
    s1 = serial.Serial(port,9600)

    time.sleep(0.1)

    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        image = frame.array

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        lower_range = np.array([110,50,50])
        upper_range = np.array([130,255,255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
        #cv2.imshow("Frame",image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,225,0)
        im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

        #cnt = contours[0]
        M = cv2.moments(thresh)

        if M['m00']!=0:
            cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            cv2.circle(image, (cx, cy), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
            print cx
            z= str(cx)+'b'      
            s1.write(z.enocde())


        else:
            cx, cy = 0, 0

        cv2.imshow("TERMINATOR",image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        enter code here
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        if key == ord("q"):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

)
```

```
#include <Servo.h>
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//SoftwareSerial data_serial(52 , 36); // RX, TX
//SoftwareSerial data_serial2(9, 11); // RX, TX
char m[10];
char n;
int count;
int i=0;
float value;
const int Oina1 = 12;
const int Oina2 = 13;
const int Oina3 = 9;
const int Oina4 = 8;

const int Oinb1 = 6;
const int Oinb2 = 7;
const int Oinb3 = 3;
const int Oinb4 = 2;
int Oena1=11;
int Oena2=10;
int Oenb1=5;
int Oenb2=4;
int spray=14;

Servo servo01;
Servo servo02;
Servo servo03;
Servo servo04;
Servo servo05;
Servo servo06;
int servo1Pos, servo2Pos, servo3Pos, servo4Pos, servo5Pos, servo6Pos; // current position
int servo1PPos, servo2PPos, servo3PPos, servo4PPos, servo5PPos, servo6PPos; // previous position


void setup() {

  pinMode(Oina1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oina2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oina3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oina4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oinb1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oinb2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oinb3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oinb4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oena1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oena2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oenb1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Oenb2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(spray,OUTPUT);
  servo02.attach(22);
  servo03.attach(23);
  servo05.attach(24);
  servo06.attach(25);
  servo2PPos = 100;
  servo02.write(servo2PPos);
  servo3PPos = 10;
  servo03.write(servo3PPos);
  servo5PPos = 10;
  servo05.write(servo5PPos);
  servo6PPos = 100;
  servo06.write(servo6PPos);
  Serial.begin(9600);
 // Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()){
  n=Serial.read();
 if(n =='b'){
  value=atof(m);
   Serial.println("y-axis:");
  Serial.println(value);

  i=0;
  m[0]=0;
  m[1]=0;
  m[2]=0;
  m[3]=0;

} 
else{
m[i]=n;
i++;
}
}

  if(value>=180 && value<=400){
    while(value>=180 && value<=400){
      Stop();
    pick();
    }


  }

  sideways();



}
void pick(){

 for(int i=100;i<=160;i++){ 
    servo02.write(i);
    delay(20);
 }
 for(int j=10;j<=50;j++){ 
    servo03.write(j);
   delay(20);
 }
 for(int k=10;k<=50;k++){ 
    servo05.write(k);
  delay(20);
 }
 for(int l=100;l>=0;l--){
     servo06.write(l);
   delay(20);
 }


}
void sideways()
{
  analogWrite(Oena1,50);
  analogWrite(Oena2,50);
   analogWrite(Oenb1,50);
  analogWrite(Oenb2,50);


  digitalWrite(Oina1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Oina2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oina3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oina4,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(Oinb1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oinb2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oinb3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oinb4,LOW);


}
void frontways()
{
  analogWrite(Oena1,50);
  analogWrite(Oena2,50);
   analogWrite(Oenb1,50);
  analogWrite(Oenb2,50);


  digitalWrite(Oina1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oina2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oina3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oina4,LOW);
   digitalWrite(Oinb1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Oinb2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oinb3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Oinb4,LOW);


}
void Stop()
{
  analogWrite(Oena1,50);
  analogWrite(Oena2,50);
   analogWrite(Oenb1,50);
  analogWrite(Oenb2,50);


  digitalWrite(Oina1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oina2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oina3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oina4,LOW);
   digitalWrite(Oinb1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oinb2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Oinb3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Oinb4,LOW);


}
```

Comment: The problem is not on your Rpi's Python code but in your Arduino. What method are you using to read? I think it's not parsing it as the correct type (float I guess). Can you show your Arduino code?

Comment: Hello i have edited with Arduino code.I made the serial.available work . Serial.read no longer shows -1 but can't display the value. Please help!!!

Comment: I cannot make any sense of your Arduino code. If you are supposed to be reading coordinates why are you just reading bytes one by one and comparing with b? To debug you should read data from the serial port on your Python code, where do you see the println results? Are you opening the same port from your Python code and the Arduino serial console?